# C++ - how to send a HTTP post request using Curlpp or libcurl

Tags: c++, http, libcurl, curlpp

I would like to send an http post request in c++. It seems like libcurl (Curlpp) is the way to go.

Now, here is a typical request that am sending

```
http://abc.com:3456/handler1/start?<name-Value pairs>

The name values pairs will have:

field1: ABC
field2: b, c, d, e, f
field3: XYZ

etc.
```

Now, I would like to know how to achieve the same using curlpp or libcurl.
Code snippets will really help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't have experience with Curlpp but this is how I did it with libcurl.

You can set your target url using

```
curl_easy_setopt(m_CurlPtr, CURLOPT_URL, "http://urlhere.com/");
```

POST values are stored in a linked list -- you should have two variables to hold the begin and the end of that list so that cURL can add a value to it.

```
struct curl_httppost* beginPostList;
struct curl_httppost* endPostList;
```

You can then add this post variable using

```
curl_formadd(&beginPostList, &endPostList, CURLFORM_COPYNAME, "key", CURLFORM_COPYCONTENTS, "value", CURLFORM_END);
```

Submitting then works like this

```
curl_easy_setopt(m_CurlPtr, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_easy_setopt(m_CurlPtr, CURLOPT_HTTPPOST, beginPostList); 
curl_easy_perform(m_CurlPtr);
```

Hope this helps!